# Snooping on pseudo terminal

Tags: c++, linux, tty, pts

I want to write a program that can capture the input/output of a pseudo terminal without it affecting the original terminal. It can be likened to pointing `script` to a `/dev/pts/<n>`.

**Use Case:** A user ssh's into my machine and runs an interactive tool. With audit, I can see commands running but I need to see the output also. I can listen in on `/dev/pts/<n>` but then the original logged in user does not get the output.

I want to write my own program to handle this case. Is this problem actually solvable and if so, where should I be looking to find a solution?

Comment: No such capability exists in the pty driver. Your only reasonable action is implementing a MITM pty proxy yourself,

Comment: @SamVarshavchik then you have to modify the ssh server to use that "MITM pty proxy" instead of just running the user's login shell directly, at which point you may wonder whether it wouldn't be easier to let ssh itself log all the data read and written to that pseudo-terminal ;-)

Comment: It should be possible, @user414777 to instruct `ssh` to execute your wrapper as the alleged shell, which then sets up a proxy and executes the real shell as the subprocess it controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's solvable by using `ptrace(2)` on the ssh server process which handles to master end of the pseudo-terminal (which is usually the parent process of the shell running in the terminal).

You can start with `strace` which is itself using `ptrace(2)`, e.g.

```
strace -p <pid> -e trace=read,write \
  -e read=<fds opened to /dev/ptmx> \
  -e write=<fds opened to /dev/ptmx>
```

This will show you everything that's read or written to that pseudo-terminal. You can get the "fds opened to /dev/ptmx" from `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd`.

You can then look at what `strace` is doing -- e.g. by stracing strace itself with

```
strace -e trace=ptrace,process_vm_readv strace ...
```

and by studying its source code.

You can of course modify the ssh server itself to log all that info, or just tweak its config options (e.g. `LogLevel` -- which can be modified on a per-user or connecting host basis).

Comment: Thank you. I had used strace before but hooked onto the bash psuedoterminal which never showed the reads but using the parent sshd i could see both directions. Now onto the arduous task of parsing the output :)